# Вектор строки превратить в нормальный вид Python

Tags: python, vector

В базе есть вектор строки тип поля Longtext

> ```
> -0.0261852 0.110802  -0.0236367 -0.0658787 
> -0.112646 -0.0223113 -0.0166133 -0.0676538 
>  0.185618 -0.0883742 -0.0166133 -0.0676538
> ```

Примерно такой вид. 
Мне надо чтобы было при выходе было не String а Vector.

> [-0.0261852, 0.110802, -0.0236367, -0.0658787,
>        -0.112646, -0.0223113, -0.0166133, -0.0676538,
>         0.185618, -0.0883742, -0.0166133, -0.0676538]

главное чтоб тип был не String.

Пытался запихнуть в `np.array(dbvector)` не помогает, 
так же писал `dlib.vector(dbVector)` не помогает.

Comment: а что за база? что за тип у вектора?

Comment: в Питоне нет ни String не Vector типа встроенных. Вы вероятно имели ввиду str и  list? К примеру, `L = list(map(float, ".1 .2".split()))`

Comment: В указанном вами примере для Longtext поля - это одна строка с переводами строк или три строки?